# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "," using chessboard.js

Tags: javascript, html, chess

I am making a chess engine using Chessboard.js but i have a problem... my coding that is wrong is this:

```
var board,
game = new Chess();
```

and the page says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chessboard-0.3.0.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
<script src="pro chess.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Webpage at: chessboardjs.com/

Comment: Just a guess but maybe it's because you declare those variables on a separate/new line causing a syntax error. Place them both on the same line / in-line and run the script again. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Try the following sample jsfiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/pebreo/amXhC/

Comment: That does not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Should be a semi colon, not a comma. Semi colon is used to denote the end of a statement.

var board;
game = new Chess();

Comment: yes  i know but it still says the same thing and this is what chessboard.js examples did.

Comment: Which page are you looking at? I did not see anything at a quick glance. The comment on your original question tells how to define multiple variables on one line if that is what you are after. Also can you provide your HTML in the question?